# Differences between Eclipse and Ant build on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have an android app that utilizes the iText libraries for generating PDFs.  The application compiles and works as expected while using Eclipse to build and package the apk.  I am now attempting to use ant to perform my release  builds and for some reason it cannot find java.awt.Image in its search path

Just for reference the specific API that is failing is shown below

```
[javac] class file for java.awt.Image not found
[javac] com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(photo.getPhotoPath());
```

I can use the command to package the debug apk below if I have already compiled the classes with eclipse.  Not really useful but it works

```
ant debug
```

So my question is this, How do I determine how the eclipse build is finding the java.awt.Image class in order to add it to an ant build.

Comment: After looking at the iText api, the only reason that java.awt.Image is needed is for some other methods which I am not using.  The eclipse build is behaving like it has a reference to the jre(java.awt.Image) and allowing it to compile and produce the class file.  Unfortunately I can't seem to find where that reference has been established.   I've attempted both the suggestions below but the "android update project" didn't build a different build.xml file and the build path has everything I'm expecting.  I have all my jars in the libs directory.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse click Project > Properties > Java Build Path, it contains all classpath settings which eclipse use

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run the command to make Android create build scripts for your project (details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)):

```
android update <project-name> -p .
```

This will generate build.xml, now compare and see what you missed.

Comment: This doesn't always seem to work, the file is generated but the build.xml doesn't work even though it compiles in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before , just update your java jdk.